# Abstract Grid for GUI in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

For an assignment, I need to create a class which inherits from tk.Canvas which essentially forms an "Abstract Grid"-  a grid with a set number of rows and columns, and they should all support creation of text at specific positions based on row and column

I know that tkinter already has an in-built grid but how would I initialise a portion of that grid, say an a x b area depending on how many rows or columns i input into my argument, and how would I return the position of a widget within that grid?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a grid with `cell_cols` (the x-count) by `cell_rows` (the y-count)

Then it all comes down to the width and height of the Canvas in pixels.

The top-left `pixel_x` and `pixel_y` pixel coordinates of the cell at grid `grid_x`, `grid_y` is always going to be:

```
pixel_x = grid_x * canvas.width // cell_cols 
pixel_y = grid_y * canvas.height // cell_rows
```

Assuming a 0 → width-1 and 0 → height-1 coordinate system (I'm not 100% sure for Tkinter)

If you allow your window to be resizable (which is a good idea), you will need to re-calculate the positions every time.  I would just make this the default method, then it's flexible for later changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily subclass `tk.Canvas`, and give it the desired behavior:

> creation of text at specific positions based on row and column

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

class TextGrid(tk.Canvas):
    
    def __init__(self, rows, cols, master):
        self.master = master
        super().__init__(self.master)
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        
    def create_text_at(self, row, col, text):
        """support creation of text at specific positions based on row and column
        """
        x = self.winfo_width() // self.cols * (col + .5)
        y = self.winfo_height() // self.rows * (row + .5)
        self.create_text(x, y, text=text)
        
def write_text():
    row = int(row_entry.get())
    col = int(col_entry.get())
    text = txt_entry.get()
    tcv.create_text_at(row, col, text)
        
root = tk.Tk()
tcv = TextGrid(10, 12, root)
tcv.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

tk.Label(root, text='col').pack()
col_entry = tk.Entry(root)
col_entry.pack()
tk.Label(root, text='row').pack()
row_entry = tk.Entry(root)
row_entry.pack()
tk.Label(root, text='text').pack()
txt_entry = tk.Entry(root)
txt_entry.pack()
cmf = tk.Button(root, text='confirm', command=write_text)
cmf.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]